# Using env in React Native, google places auto complete

Tags: react-native, google-places-autocomplete

I have a .env file with the following

```
GOOGLE_PLACES_API = 12345
```

in my react native i import them as

```
const GOOGLE_PLACES_API = process.env[GOOGLE_PLACES_API"]
```

If I put it in my view like

```
<Text> {GOOGLE_PLACES_API} <Text />
```

it displays on screen '12345'

Now when I place it in googlePlacesAutoComplete:

```
<GooglePlacesAutoComplete 
  query= {{ key: {GOOGLE_PLACES_API} }}
/>
```

it doesn't work.
I have tried

```
<GooglePlacesAutoComplete 
  query= {{ key: "12345" }}
/>
```

which will work.

How can I use the env in the key for googleplaces

Answer (score 0):

this is the thing you are looking for :)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dotenv

Also seems like you've added unnecesary brackets

```
key: {GOOGLE_PLACES_API} should be key: GOOGLE_PLACES_API
```

Comment: stange, I could console.log(GOOGLE_PLACES_API), 
but when i put it in 
<GooglePlacesAutoComplete query={{Key: GOOGLE_PLACES_API}} />

then it won't work, until I put back
<GooglePlacesAutoComplete query={{Key:  "12345}} />

Comment: `const GOOGLE_PLACES_API = process.env[GOOGLE_PLACES_API"]` you also missed missing opening quote "GOOGLE...

Comment: I missed the opening quote here. but back in my code. its correct. 
Ive also changed the way i use it, following the link you send. Now I 'import { GOOGLE_PLACE_API} from '@env'